# Windows directory listing: dirs on top of list vs bottom

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

When I browse a directory & my settings are "View->Details" usually the dirs are all listed at top i.e. head of the list. This is how I prefer it.

But every once in a while, inexplicably (to me) the dirs go to the bottom of the list and individual files appear at the top.

Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing? What controls whether windows explorer will list dirs before files or the other way around?

If it matters I'm using Win-8.

Comment: Clicking the header of the `Name` column changes the sort order ascending - descending. When descending the folders are at the bottom

Comment: @TomBrunberg Thanks. But I usually use "Sort by->Date Modified". Usually that's how I want it.

Comment: Yes, I just told you what may be the cause of the "wrong" order. Another one is clicking the header of the `Size` column. The folders are regarded as no size.

Comment: @TomBrunberg So, say, I wanted to list with the newest files on top. Then should the dirs list on top or on bottom. And is there no way to control this independently?